# How to wait until XAJAX call completed before doing something else

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-chosen

I have to wait untill Xajax gets its response from server so I can use thise reponse with a Jquery plugin :

In this example I have to wait untill the select box is created (by an XAJAX call) before I apply the plugin `.chosen()` on it:

```
<? $objResponse = new xajaxResponse();
$objResponse->assign($selectID, 'innerHTML', $codeThatCreatesSelectBox);
$objResponse->script('$(function(){ $("#selectID").chosen(); });');
return $objResponse; ?>
```

I tried using jquery function AjaxComplete() but it dosen't seem to work since Jquery and Xajax are two different things :

```
$objResponse->script('$("#selectID").ajaxComplete(function() {$("#selectID").chosen(); });');
```

How Can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a synchronous AJAX-request.
The difference is discussed here: [AJAX sync and async difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5528852/ajax-sync-and-async-difference)

Here is how you do it in XAJAX: http://community.xajax-project.org/topic/6460/synchonous-requests-with-parameters-fails-completely/